# Calculating distance between user & a nearby location, and calculated distance keeps showing up as 0?

Tags: uitableview, mkmapview, mkannotation, xcode4.6

I'm using the following code to calculate the distance between my app user's location, and nearby locations (annotations). When I try to display the "Distance Away" as text in a label, it keeps saying that the calculated distance is 0. Why is this?

*Note that my table is using the coordinates placed on my MapView to determine the distance away.

Here's the code I'm using to calculate the distance from my user to a nearby location

**MapViewController.m**

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

   for (MapViewAnnotation *annotation in self.mapView.annotations) {
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [annotation coordinate];
CLLocation *annotationLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coord.latitude longitude:coord.longitude];
annotation.distance = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:annotationLocation];



    }
```

And here's the bit I'm using to display the calculatedDistance in a label (located in my custom cell to be displayed in a tableview):

**ViewController.m**

```
cell.distanceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f m.", calculatedDistance];
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (MapViewAnnotation *annotation in self.mapView.annotations) {
  CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [annotation coordinate];
  CLLocation *userLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coord.latitude longitude:coord.longitude];
```

That's not the user's location, that's the annotation's location. But odd variable names aside:

```
CLLocationDistance calculatedDistance = [userLocation distanceFromLocation:userLocation];
```

The distance from a location to itself is 0. **That line is probably a bug.** Maybe you meant

```
CLLocationDistance calculatedDistance = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:userLocation];
```

which would return the distance between the user's new location and the (misnamed) annotation's location - probably what you want. Of course, you actually calculate just that on the line above the distance-to-self calculation, then throw it away two lines later.

## tl;dr

Throw away the last two lines, they're useless.

Comment: I scrapped the last two lines, and changed my variable name (lol). See updated code above. Is that what I should end up with? Don't I need to define the calculatedDistance? Thanks for your help, btw!

Comment: Just pull it (the distance) out of the annotation in the display code, or something. (Besides, the single variable `calculatedDistance` is inadequate for holding multiple distances (as it was asked to do in the `for` loop).)

Comment: Ok, I totally see now why my last 2 lines were useless, lol. Can you show me w/ code how this would look? I'm a bit confused! Thx :)